# Why was Shishupala born with three eyes and four arms?

Tags: mahabharata, karma, body

From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/932/6981) answer by Keshav Srinivasan,
Shishupala had three eyes and four arms.

> When Shishupala was born, he had three eyes and four arms, which terrified his parents, the king and queen of Chedi.

Why did he have this extra eye and arms?

Answer (score 1):

The curse upon Shishupala's birth is explained in the Mahabharata (Sabha Parva, Chapter 38). It is said that Shishupala was an incarnation of the demon Hiranyakashipu's gatekeeper, Jaya. Due to Jaya's insolence and misbehaviour towards Lord Vishnu, he was cursed by the four Kumaras (four sages) to be born a demon with three eyes. However, it was also foretold that Lord Vishnu would kill him.